# Fourier Sine Transform for a system

Tags: fourier-analysis, partial-derivative, fourier-transform

In my class we began to study the Fourier transform, applying it to differential equations.
But, I do not fully understand the issue of initial conditions and border, using the Fourier sine transform.

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^{2} Y(X,t)}{\partial t^{2}} = 4\frac{\partial^{2} Y(X,t)}{\partial X^{2}}\\
With: \\
Y(0,t) = 0\\
Y(4,t) = 0\\
Y(X,0) = a_{0}X\\
Y_{t}(X,0)=b_{0}X(d_{0}-X)\\
0 < X < 4; 0 < t 
\end{equation}
Where $Y_{t}(X,0)$ It's the derivative with respect to t

Also, if I have 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^{2} U}{\partial X^{2}}\\
U(0,t) = 1\\
U(\pi,t) = 3\\
U(X,0)=2\\
0 < X < \pi; 0<t 
\end{equation}

It would be a similar process as the first one? Or it changes due to what the system asks

Thanks you

Comment: In your first equation, how is it that $Y\left(4,t\right)=0\Longrightarrow Y\left(4,0\right)=0$ while also $Y\left(X,0\right)=a_{0}X\Longrightarrow Y\left(4,0\right)=4a_{0}$?

Comment: That's what I don't get. I have a particular case, but i would like ti understand the general system.

Comment: The problem as you posted it doesn't make sense. The boundary & initial condition contradict one another. Once you have a well-defined problem we can try to explain what you should do, as well as the general theory.